# Linear Classifier Tensorflow2 not training(1 neuron model)

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, tensorflow2.0

I'm currently working on the CIFAR-10 Dataset which is an image classification problem with 10 classes.

I have started to develop with Tensorflow 2 a Linear Classification without the LinearClassifier Object.

- X shape corresponds to 10 000 images of 32*32 pixels RBG = (10000, 3072)
- Y_one_hot is a one hot vector  = (10000, 10)

**model creation code:**

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear", input_dim=32*32*3))
model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax", input_dim=1))
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

**training code:**

```
model.fit(X, Y_one_hot, batch_size=10000, verbose=1, epochs=100)
```

**predict code:**

```
img = X[0].reshape(1, 3072) # Select image 0
res = np.argmax((model.predict(img))) # select the max in output
```

**Problem:**

res value is always the same. It seems my model is not learning.

Model.summary

**Summary displays :**

```
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 3073      
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 10)                20        
Total params: 3,093
Trainable params: 3,093
Non-trainable params: 0
```

**Accuracy & loss:**

```
Epoch 1/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 2s 184us/sample - loss: 0.0949 - accuracy: 0.1005

Epoch 50/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 10us/sample - loss: 0.0901 - accuracy: 0.1000

Epoch 100/100
10000/10000 [==============================] - 0s 8us/sample - loss: 0.0901 - accuracy: 0.1027
```

Do you have any idea why my model is always prediciting the same value ?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you also add accuracy of each trainning epochs and the summary of the model by using. ```model.summary()```

Comment: I have added summary and accuracy to the question

Answer (score 1):

One remarks:

The loss you used `loss="mean_squared_error"`is not meant for classification. Is meant for regression. Two very different problems. Try a cross entropy. For example

```
`model.compile(optimizer=AdamOpt, 
      loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])`
```

You can find an example here: https://github.com/michelucci/oreilly-london-ai/blob/master/day1/Beginner%20friendly%20networks/First_Example_of_a_CNN_(CIFAR10).ipynb. Is a note book I used for a training I gave. The network is CNN but you can change it with yours.

Try that...

Best of luck, Umberto